# What are the best legal methods to protect one's jewelry designs?

Tags: intellectual-property, international, british-columbia, ohio, mexico

As handcrafted jewelry producers, our cooperative has created literally thousands
of  original jewelry designs over the past 30 + years. What would be the most effective
and practical ways to protect our authorship rights and to defend ourselves
from disrespectful commercial predators?

Comment: The answers are all correct, however you have to pursue claims against those infringing, the government won't do it for you. That means having the ability to have a lawyer and the funding to sue.

Comment: In the most unlikely case of winning such a lawsuit,, the Defendant would not pay. I believe this would entail further expenses with kittle or no chance of ever collecting.

Comment: I would like to know what is wrong with this question to deserve a down-vote.

Comment: I wonder why you think winning such a suit us "most unlikely"? As for collecting damages, that very much depends on the circumstances, but if a losing defendant has a bank account, its contents can often be seized.

Comment: @RonBeyer could this: “17 U.S.C. § 506(a), which provides that "[a]ny person who infringes a copyright willfully and for purposes of commercial advantage or private financial gain" shall be punished as provided in 18 U.S.C. § 2319. Section 2319 provides, in pertinent part, that a 5-year felony shall apply if the offense” not prompt some executive agencies to take action? Maybe on the report of the copyright holder or otherwise?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but my guess would be that it's in reaction to your request for specific legal advice, which is considered off-topic.

Comment: @bdb484 I wonder how to correctly phrase a question then; since I was not asking for legal advice; only researching how the legal system works in theory.

Comment: @David Siegel The theft of jewelry designs is extraordinarily common. Buyers do not think there is anything wrong with having a design copied.  It is interesting to learn that 17 U.S.C. § 506(a) prohibits the appropriation of the creative product of an artisan and that 18 U.S.C. § 2319. Section 231 provides for serious penalties. No matter what laws may be on the books, itsw hard for me to believe that an ordinary silversmith could realistically make use of them, as a practical matter.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz I remember to have learned about this in 2nd or 3rd grade (European jurisdiction), basically, that we cannot falsely claim authorship of a copyright-subject work of art (specifically talking about poems), or modify it, and claim it to be ours. I would agree with David Siegel; what is not plausible: How a silversmith could realistically afford a U.S. an attorney from Mexico. Maybe that's the root of the commonness. Many people can potentially form a class or collective which may make it better worth it for the atty.

Comment: The question also does less appear a hypothetical than a question seeking legal advice; bdb484 warned you. ("our cooperative") Voting to close. People have to walk a fine line to have these educational discourses going, you should consider that.

Comment: It worked as a hypothetical until you started objecting to answers.

Comment: I urge others to vote to reopen.IMO this essentially asks what laws apply to a given situation. That is on-topic here.

Comment: This is ironic because I was NOT seeking specific legal advice regarding protection of jewelry design.  An experienced silversmith doubts that laws constrain buyers, they would only laugh at the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the answer by user6726](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/77466/17500) says such works are automatically protected by US copyright. It would be possible to register them with the copyright office. This is required before bringing a suit for infringement, and if done in advance, preserves the right to statutory damages under [17 USC 504](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap5.html#504). Statutory damages can be anywhere from $750 to $30,000 per work infringed, or up to $150,000 per work for wilful infringement, as the court may think just. In addition, injunctions against continued infringement are available under 17 USC 502. Under 17 USC 503 allegedly infringing copies and "plates, molds, matrices, masters, tapes, film negatives, or other articles by means of which such copies or phonorecords may be reproduced;" may be impounded. and if the plaintiff wins,

> the court may order the destruction or other reasonable disposition of all copies or phonorecords found to have been made or used in violation of the copyright owner’s exclusive rights, and of all plates, molds, matrices, masters, tapes, film negatives, or other articles by means of which such copies or phonorecords may be reproduced.

I believe that "other reasonable disposition " can sometimes include turning infringing copies over to the successful plaintiff.

However, registration requires payment of a [fee](https://www.copyright.gov/about/fees.html) currently $45 for a single work, or $85 for a group of up to 10 unpublished works. Registering thousands of designs would involve significant costs.

It would be possible for a group of artisans to design and adopt a trademark, and use this on future works, or even incorporate it into the design.

Under [15 USC 1116](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/1116)(d) items offered for sale containing  a counterfeit trademark can be seized on suitable application from the trademark owner, but the owner may be liable for damages if this leads to a false seizure.

Damages may be obtained if a trademark is improperly used without permission. Such seized items may later be ordered destroyed. Some of this applies only to registered trademarks. However, trademark registration is a somewhat complex process, and there are fees and expenses involved. Non-US persons are, I understand, required to employ a US trademark attorney, and others are strongly advised to do so.

See [15 USC Chapter 22](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/chapter-22) for the whole trademark law.

Comment: Answer accepted, even though the registration costs are prohibitive; also, what the lawyer would charge (if we could ever get one to talk with us) and other legal expenses.

Comment: And It would have to be a specialized  lawyer who understands jewelry-design.

Comment: @Maria Alaniz copyright registration costs, done in groups of 10, would be only $8.50 per design, and no lawyer would be needed for that. Doing the newer design first and othe4s as funds permitted or as infringements are noted  might help. Trademark registration costs might well be prohibitive, but some trademark protection can be gained from use without registration.

Comment: @DavidSiegel What would be the practical form of registering a copyright for a piece of jewel? Photos, video or stereoscopic video evidence of the original?

Comment: http://ethical-fair-trade-jewelry.org/federation-of-northamerican-indigenous-artisan-communities/artisan-intellectual-property/ @kisspuska Here find examples of line-drawings used by jewelry makers to define their creations before making them.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz these descriptions, and drawings may very well establish copyright for their drafter, but I could only imagine them provide any copyright protection for the jewel _itself_ via the right to derivative works, _maybe_. Such descriptions and figures could prove useful as the basis of drafting up a design patent as well (there are free _pro se_ patent assistance services at the USPTO, not sure if they provide services for non-utility patent prosecution—George White I'm sure does). So, I wonder what steps the U.S. copyright registration would entail in case of a piece of jewel.

Answer (score 3):

A work of art is protected by copyright, under US copyright law – see [here](https://www.copyright.gov/comp3/chap900/ch900-visual-art.pdf) esp. §908.

> Jewelry designs are typically protected under the U.S. copyright law
> as sculptural works, although in rare cases they may be protected as
> pictorial works. This Section discusses certain issues that commonly
> arise in connection with such works.

(followed by a discussion of what jewelry is). The item must be "sufficiently creative or
expressive", which we will take to be self-evidently true.

Comment: Notably, fashion designs and recipes are typically not capable of obtaining intellectual property protections except for specific concrete written descriptions of them.

Comment: Examples of our jewelry designs with "concrete written descriptions" ,http://ethical-fair-trade-jewelry.org/federation-of-northamerican-indigenous-artisan-communities/artisan-intellectual-property/

Comment: -1 I would respectfully suggest more specificity especially in consideration of the Mexico and international tags since the U.S. uniquely needs a registration for that copyright not only be subject to the probably never prosecuted criminal form of violations, and a holder be able to sue on them. And the retrospectivity of the registration for purposes of seeking damages is limited. Anyone outside of the U.S. reading this answer would never even imagine any requirement of registration.

Comment: @kisspuska "Anyone outside of the U.S. reading this answer would never even imagine any requirement of registration." – Why do you say this? In many respects, USA and Mexico laws have been coordinated.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz “[Because] the U.S. **uniquely** needs a registration for [a] copyright”.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz for that point: All the more reason that it’d better be spelled out: Since based on that expectation, you probably would even less so expect that the U.S. is different from Mexico where registration of a copyright for a work of art is, as no where else in the world, not a legal requirement for any legal action.

Comment: @kisspuska Please believe me when I tell you that I have NOT been thinking of involving myself in any sort of legal action based on copyrighting works of art in the USA. Only in getting all the relevant legal information regarding jewelry design trademarks on a single page, in the form of Answers to my Question.  Thanks so much for your help with that.

Comment: @kisspuska "Anyone outside of the U.S. reading this answer would never even imagine any requirement of registration. – " It is given out in Mexican government conferences that formal registration is needed for trademark protection. It's news to me that this is not a legal requirement in Mexico. Makes no difference though, because of the costs of winning a judgement. and the difficulty in collecting any such judgement. I assure you, the Buyers would just die laughing at our lovely expensive trademark protection. I know because i live in a city of thousands of silversmiths. Taxco de Alarcon.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz copyrights and trademarks are different breeds. bdb484, as well as I, was talking about copyrights here. Copyrights registration is a unique procedure to the U.S. Trademarks and patents (both design and utility) can be registered elsewhere too. Your question related to “legal methods” of intellectual property protection of jewelry design.

Comment: Thank you @kisspuska Trademarks registration in Mexico must be filed before the Mexican Institute of Industrial Property ("IMPI") .  As for written works, its 'Indautor' https://www.indautor.gob.mx/mision-y-vision.php "... responsible for the registration and protection of copyright and related rights." Our master catalog has 2000+ styles; the cost of registering all these is considerable. Forgive me if I suspect that their data base is a mess and that all they do is collect fees and issue certificates, without any way to compare one design with another.

Answer (score 1):

For new designs a design patent might be appropriate in the U.S. Note that they are for manufactured articles. Manufacturing does not exclude things made by hand but if each item is individually, uniquely designed then it wouldn’t work for you. In most other countries there is a similar protection for the ornamental design of products but it is not usually under the location’s patent system.

Comment: Jewelry designs are usually created as "original-models" to make a mold or a stamping tool for purposes of production in series. Problem is an attorney or a judge who is not a silversmith would not be able to understand the line-drawings that are used to create the prototype (original-model).

Comment: There are design patents for all types of items. See this example of one for a jewelry item https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/70/d7/ef/82b65cd8eba3df/USD549126S1.pdf

Comment: @MariaAlaniz "Problem is an attorney or a judge who is not a silversmith would not be able to understand the line-drawings that are used to create the prototype (original-model)", if you doubt the integrity of a system, that's one thing. But doubting the intellectual abilities of atty's/judge's specializing in the fields of copyrights & patents is highly presumptuous and misguided. Utility patents, if I'm not mistaken, are disputed in one federal district (possibly done similarly in design patents?), but I'd assume that absent utility aspects, other judges could handle these cases no problem.

Comment: @kisspuska - in the US it is only appeals that go to a special  court that hears patent appeals. But your comment is very valid otherwise.

Comment: @George White thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @kisspusa "doubting the intellectual abilities of atty's/judge's specializing in the fields of copyrights & patents is highly presumptuous and misguided."  Presumptious perhaps, but misguided I think not. If the relevant experts, attornies, and judges could create a piece of jewelry from our relatively simple designs, I would believe these officials were qualified. However, if the marking authorities can't make the piece themselves with only the line art to inform them,, then they are NOT really qualified to legally characterize an original jewelry design.

Comment: http://ethical-fair-trade-jewelry.org/federation-of-northamerican-indigenous-artisan-communities/artisan-intellectual-property/ here are examples of our line-art; do you believe that a marking official is able to create the physical piece it describes? A qualified silversmith can. A burocrat or a lawyer or a government funcionary who does not even know if a piece is casted or constructed from sheet and wire is only able to provide documentation of dubious value. Sorry. I am trying to explain., not attempting to turn the world upside down.

Comment: A design patent is to allow you to try to stop someone from making something that looks like your product. It is not meant to be a document one uses like a blueprint as a basis for making an exact duplicate. Your line drawings could be used - but better than that design patent drawings also have shading and views from all sides to better depict the item. There is nothing about your designs you linked to that are out of the ordinary designs covered by design patents. The material and actual construction details are not covered by design patents just the overall look.

Comment: "A design patent is to allow you to try to stop someone from making something that looks like your product." @George White I have seen jewelry design art that a upon visuakl inspection a laymen might deem acceptable. Even though to make the piece itself from this art were impossible; or at least it would be ambiguous. I would never pay good money to have a non-silversmith lawyer or government official to characterize a piece of jewelry as unique or authentic, if that person is not qualified to reproduce that piece. I am not being contrary. Just providing the point of view of an artisan.

Comment: We are speaking past each other. A design patent will stop someone from making a seeming ripoff of your work whether or not it is a good ripoff. It is to your advantage that both good and poor imitations would be prohibited.